# Combobox traz somente um resultado da tabela do Mysql (NodeJS + JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, combobox

Estou conseguindo trazer no combobox somente um valor que está na tabela do mysql, preciso que sejam listados os dois itens na mesma combobox. Está aparecendo um em uma combobox e o na outra logo abaixo.

```
<div class="container">
    <% if(busca.length > 0) { %>
        <% for(var i = 0; i < busca.length; i++) {%> 
            <select>
                <option value="0"selected="selected"><%=busca[i].category_name%></option>
            </select>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar as tags select fora do loop:

```
<% if(busca.length > 0) { %>
    <select>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < busca.length; i++) {%> 
            <option value="0"selected="selected"><%=busca[i].category_name%></option>
    <% } %>
    </select>
```

Comment: Guilherme Costamilam Muito obrigado!!  Funcionou como eu precisava!